# How secure is Local Hadoop Installation without password?

Tags: macos, hadoop, ssh

I want to install hadoop 2.6 in pseudo-distributed mode on my Mac following the instruction found in the blog http://zhongyaonan.com/hadoop-tutorial/setting-up-hadoop-2-6-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html

The blogger suggests to execute the commands:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

to allow ssh connection to localhost without password. I don't know anything about ssh, sorry for the very basic following concern. Can anyone please tell me:

1. Is it secure to run these command? Or I am granting any kind of public remote access to my pc? (I told you it was a very basic question)
2. How can I undo the authorisation I previously granted with these commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, *no Hadoop is secure without Kerberos*. That's not closely related to what you're doing generating SSH keys.

In any case, SSH keys require you to have both a public and private key. No one can access the cluster without the generated private key. And no one can access the cluster if their key isn't in the authorized file.

To put it simply, the commands are only as secure as the computer you're running them on. For example, some bad actor could be remotely coping all generated SSH keys on the system.

These passwordless SSH keys are for the hadoop services to communicate between each other within the cluster, and each process should be ran with limited system access anyway, not elevated / root privileges.

You undo the operation by ultimately destroying the key, but you can prevent access by just removing the entry from the authorized file

Comment: Very clear, thanks. As you are mentioning it, could you please tell also whether is it possible to run _Kerberos_ in pseudo-distributed mode and if it makes any sense?

Comment: It doesn't make sense other than learning purposes. But, it is in the documentation. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SecureMode.html#Hadoop_in_Secure_Mode Also, I personally don't recommend anyone just goes and install and configure base Hadoop by itself. Ambari or Cloudera Manager make all the automated installs and monitoring of Hadoop services much, much easier.

Comment: Hortonworks, MapR, and Cloudera each provide a hadoop sandbox VM that include a lot of services setup for you. Kerberos being optional